# Recording all using sounds as one track (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I work with Cocos2d. This CocosDention not have the property that i need.
Maybe anybody know what the way record and save to file all sound using in the current stage on ios. How about DJ app - they keep the music from different pieces and put them on each other.

For example, in the game play background music. When player jumping, cocosdenchion can play jumping sound. Can i create new track combine background music and other music effects realtime and save it?

How i understand AVAudioRecorder only for recording for microphone devices.
What i can use for this – AudioToolbox? OpenAL? CoreAudio? Other frameworks?

Before i think use FMOD, but there are license 500$ and i'm not sure my project give me some match money. On this i find free method or framework. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solution. I use [BASS iOS library](http://www.un4seen.com).
one minus – it's paid. And second minus – it's written on C++. 
And not some example for iOS. But have good help on the forum.

```
    //BASS initialisation. use BASS_free for free resources
    BASS_Init(-1,44100,0,NULL,NULL);

    //create mixer
    BASS_GetInfo(&info); // get output device info. needet to get freq
    mixer=BASS_Mixer_StreamCreate(info.freq, 2, 0); // create a stereo mixer with the same sample rate
NSString *shortSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"piano2" ofType:@"wav"];
    //create channel
    chan2 = BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [shortSound cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_DECODE);

    //create channel from file use absolute path url
    NSString *soundFileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ff13" ofType:@"mp3"];
    chan = BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [soundFileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_DECODE|BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT|BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);

    //add channel into mixer
    BASS_Mixer_StreamAddChannel(mixer, chan, 0);

    //point the dirrectory and file name for our new file saved mixer data
    NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [documentDir stringByAppendingString:@"/file.mp3"];

    //start encode mixer to file when view did load. With parameters for encode.
    BASS_Encode_StartCAFile(mixer, 'm4af', 'alac', 0, 0, [filename cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    //mixer add any delay for play added channel. Fix it using this option
    BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(mixer, BASS_ATTRIB_NOBUFFER, 1);

    BASS_ChannelPlay(mixer, 0); // start mixer
```

Here used mixer for record all sounds and microphone voice.